# Google Play does not work on Samsung S3 (GT-I9300) purchased in China Unicom

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does China Mobile Galaxy S3 model GT I-9308 have Google Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/does-china-mobile-galaxy-s3-model-gt-i-9308-have-google-play-store)

Just want to check

1. Whether Google Play support Samsung S3 (GT-i9300)?
2. I have downloaded the Google Play to S3 but it won't work?

Is there any way to use Google Play on a Samsung Galaxy S 3? (I have a Google account and it worked fine on another Smart Phone.)

Actually same issue for other Google applications like Google+, Gmail, etc.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/does-china-mobile-galaxy-s3-model-19308-have-google-play-store

Comment: Do you have the **GT-I9300** or **GT-I9308**?

Comment: Also: what errors are you seeing? "won't work" is not very specific.